# Select all elements and sub-elements in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am trying to select all the elements and sub-elements in an XML with out Specifying certain path in XSLT.

My Sample XML is

```
<Home>
<Application>One</Application>
<Property>Valid</Property>
<PR>3254</PR>
<Trigger>
  <Interface>Temp</Interface>
  <Id>234</Id>
</Trigger>
</Home>
```

OutPut Expected is

```
Application : One
Property : Valid
PR : 3254
Interface : Temp
Id : 234
```

I have used the below XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="Home/*">
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But Getting Result as follows

```
Application : One
Property : Valid
PR : 3254
Trigger: Temp234
```

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting all *leaf nodes* (nodes that do not have children elements), e.g:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[not(*)]">
```